# how to read multi integers from one text box and store in array using php?

Tags: php, arrays

Can I use php to read values from one input and store it in array?

I want to read multi integers from the user and calculate the total of them if the user entered ZERO!

For example, I add one input text and one submit:

```
<form method="GET">
enter numbers : <input type = "text" name="txt">
<input type = "submit" value = "Calculate">

</form>
```

then use php to read them !!

```
<?php
$n = @$_GET[txt];  
$i=0;
while ($n!=0)
{

$ary[$i]=$n;
$i++;

}
    if ($n==0)
echo @count($ary);     
    ?>
```

it doesn't work .. what should I do here? There is the same problem in java, but there I can use scanner. Can any one help to solve it with php?

Comment: You are supposed to put quotes around the key of an array and you'll also need to submit the form.

Comment: i tried to put quotes but still not working

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you're asking for:

```
// Get the value of the input box, note that I put `txt` in quotes 
// so I didn't need the `@`
$txt = $_GET ['txt'];

// `explode` will create an array from a string using the first 
// parameter as a delimiter
$ary = explode (' ', $txt);

// Search the array for the ZERO value
if (array_search(0, $ary) !== false) {
  // Output the sum of the array if the ZERO value is found
  echo (array_sum ($ary));
}
```

**A note**: You should almost never use the @ operator in PHP, if you do then you're likely doing some incorrect.